# Fancybox force scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, lightbox, fancybox

I'm using the jQuery Fancybox plugin to display some content on a website.  Unfortunately, when a link is clicked, the lightbox that is loaded starts at the same scroll position as the previous one.  I tried using
    self.scrollTo(0,0)
    $.scrollTo(0)
    $('#top').scrollTo();

and a few others methods to push it back to the top, but none have seemed to work.  Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Fancybox have some sort of a callback? The reason I ask is, the lightbox is probably resetting the scroll back to the same position it left of at, so you would need to somehow call the scrollTo after the lightbox is completely closed.

Also, why not use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) instead of the scrollTo (which I assume is the jQuery scrollTo plugin).

Is this link inside the lightbox? When exactly are you calling scrollTo? Do you have some code to show what you are doing?

Metropolis

**EDIT**

Try this

```
$("#element").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good idea but this code scrolls the whole document to top, not just the fancybox content. I had to do this to achieve what you wanted:

`$("#element").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
        $("#element").scrollTop(0);
    }
});`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Metropolis, I used a similar solution, but instead of $(document).scrollTop(0) I targeted $("#fancybox-inner").scrollTop(0) which worked for me.