# ScrollTop on fancybox

Tags: jquery, scroll, fancybox

I'm trying to modify an old website which uses fancybox 1.2.6. I got a lot of short links (events) on the page. When you click a link, it opens the choosen event's full description in a fancybox. No prob in Chrome, but in FF once you've scrolled the description text in fancybox, the script seems to keep the scroll position... So when you open another event description, the fancybox automatically scrolls to prev position. I've first tried

```
'callbackOnStart':function(){
    $("#fancybox-inner").scrollTop(0);
}
```

but the prob remains. Same with #fancybox-ajax and #fancybox-content... 
I've tried to replace content with ' ' on 'callbackOnClose' but of course it's too late :-) Any solution?

Comment: Have you seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602319/fancybox-force-scroll-to-top)

Comment: The word 'this' is a link...

Comment: and $(document).scrollTop(0) scroll the entire page, not the box.

Comment: OK, I found the solution. I don't know why but $("#fancy-ajax").scrollTop(0) doesn't work on the 'callbackOnStart':function() but works perfectly on the 'callbackOnShow':function()... I guess it's because the div fancy-ajax isn't reachable onStart state.

Comment: it's not very aesthetic when FF automatically scrolls the contents on top 0 once loaded but it works...